# Como Faço para meu Modal só aparecer na primeira visita do cliente ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Eu fiz um modal, esse código java que eu utilizei

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".janelaModal, .fundoModal").fadeIn();        
    $(".botao").click(function(){
    $(".janelaModal, .fundoModal").fadeIn();        
    }); 
    $(".fecharModal, .fundoModal").click(function(){
    $(".janelaModal, .fundoModal").fadeOut();});});
```

Como eu faço para que modal só apareça na primeira visita do usuário?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar [JsCookies](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie)

```
if (Cookies.get('visita') != true) {
    Cookies.set('visita', true);
    $(".janelaModal, .fundoModal").fadeIn();        
    $(".botao").click(function(){
        $(".janelaModal, .fundoModal").fadeIn();        
    }); 
    $(".fecharModal, .fundoModal").click(function(){
        $(".janelaModal, .fundoModal").fadeOut();
    });
}
```

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda, só que agora ele não fecha mais o modal, com esse código

Comment: Bem, não tenho como reproduzir o problema para te ajudar, tente mais um pouco e retorne aqui com alguma mensagem.

Comment: eu entrei no site JsCookies, na minha index eu coloquei o
 <Script src = "js.cookie.js"> </ script> e coloquei o que vc aconselhou no código acima, tem algo mais tenho que fazer ?

Comment: Não sei, preciso ver seu código de uma forma mais ampla pra entender o problema.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode armazenar esta informação no Cliente, seja através de Cookies, localStorage, sessionStorage ou IndexedDB.

Levando em consideração, que ao armazenar em um cookie esta informação irá trafegar entre o cliente e o seu servidor em cada request, assim gerando um trafego adicional de uma informação que possivelmente não será utilizada no servidor, al´m da questão que um cookie possui data de expiração, então eu diria que Cookies não são uma boa ideia para o seu cenário.

Por um outro lado, `IndexedDB` lhe fornece uma estrutura grande demais para este problema, seria como matar uma formiga com uma bomba de fusão nuclear.

Então você pode usar `localStorage` ou `sessionStorage`, porém o sessionStorage irá desaparecer assim que a aba ou o browser for fechado, então se quiser que está informação permaneça até o fim dos tempos (ou o usuario limpar o Storage), deverá escolher pelo localStorage.

lembrando que o `localStorage` uma chave e um valor, ambos como `string`, se precisar armazenar um objeto, deverá fazer uso do `JSON.parse` e do `JSON.stringify`.

```js
var json = localStorage.getItem("dados de acesso");
var dados = {};

if (!json) {
  dados = { primeiroAcesso: true };
} else {
  dados = JSON.parse(json);
}

console.log(dados);

if (dados.primeiroAcesso) {
  /* Abra o seu dialog */
  
  dados.primeiroAcesso = false;
  localStorage.setItem("dados de acesso", JSON.stringify(dados));
}

console.log(dados);
```

Como o `Snippet` roda `sandbox`, não é possível usar o localStorage no mesmo, então o exemplo acima não vai funcionar, porém você pode abri-lo no [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/duo16mn6/)

Comment: Valeu mesmo, mas onde coloco tudo isso, sou extremamente iniciante, e não quero ser programador, não quero ser dominador de java, etc, só quero aprender o necessário para fazer meu site funcionar. Agradeço muito se poder me ajudar.